# Не устанавливается ширина input в процентах

Tags: html, css

[image]
Не удается изменить ширину инпута в процентах. Как мне исправить это? Должно растянутся так как на фото

```css
.address__block {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}

.address__title {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.address__search {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.address__search-input {
  width: 60%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="address">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="address__block">
      <span class="address__title">Проверить адрес доставки</span>
      <form class="address__search">
        <input class="address__search-input" type="search">
        <button class="address__search-button">Проверить</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.address__block {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
.address__title {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.address__search {
  max-width: 953px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.address__search-input {
  max-width: 783px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите

Comment: Это ответ на мой вопрос, нашел способ